# test case execution is getting failed and it is throwing any error stack trace in command line

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor, gruntjs, cucumber, cucumberjs

I created a testcase with Protractor-cucumber framework and I have used Grunt for execution of that test case. However, at the time of execution it failed and it's not providing any error stacktrace to know why it is failing.

I've searched Google and also reviewed other *Stack Overflow* solutions but I didn't find a solution for this.

**Config File**

```js
exports.config = {

  //seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  getPageTimeout: 60000,
  allScriptsTimeout: 500000,
  directConnect:true,

  framework: 'custom',
  // path relative to the current config file
  frameworkPath: require.resolve('C:\\...\\node_modules\\protractor-cucumber-framework'),
  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome'
  },
  ignoreUncaughtExceptions:true,
  // Spec patterns are relative to this directory.
  specs: [
    './learnFramework/utility/test.feature'
  ],

  cucumberOpts: {
    require: './learnFramework/TestCases/spec.js',
    tags: false,
    profile: false,
    'no-source': true
  },
  onPrepare: function () {
    browser.ignoreSynchronization=true;
    browser.manage().window().maximize();
  }
};
```

**Spec File**

```js
module.exports=function(){
    this.Given(/^Open the browser and Load the URL$/,async function(){
        browser.get("https://google.com");
    });

    this.When(/^User entered the text in the search box$/,async function(){
        browser.sleep(5000);
        console.log(await browser.getTitle());
        await element(By.name("q")).sendKeys("facebook");
        browser.sleep(3000);
    });

    this.Then(/^click on search$/,async function(){
        browser.action().sendKeys(protractor.Key.ENTER).perform();
        browser.sleep(5000);
    });
}
```

**Error Log**

```
Running "jshint:files" (jshint) task
>> 1 file lint free.
>
Running "protractor:singlerun" (protractor) task
[00:08:29] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[00:08:29] I/direct - Using ChromeDriver directly...
>
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:50146/devtools/browser/5c09d68c-f3ff-43b2-b645-0b5c098c41d9
Feature: Title of your feature
>
    I want to use this template for my feature file
>
  Scenario: Title of your scenario
  ✓ Given Open the browser and Load the URL
  ✖ When User entered the text in the search box
  - And click on search
>
Failures:
>
[00:09:03] I/launcher - 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[00:09:03] I/launcher - chrome #01 failed 1 test(s)
[00:09:03] I/launcher - overall: 1 failed spec(s)
[00:09:03] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 1
>>>
>>> Test failed but keep the grunt process alive.
>
Done.
```

If you observe the error log "When" step has failed but there is no error stacktrace in the command line to find why it failed.

My expectation is that it should show the error stacktrace for why it has failed.

Comment: I had to install `jasmine-spec-reporter` package. Try find an equivalent for cucumber framework

Comment: I think there is no such reporter for Protractor-Cucumber framework. Do you have any other solution on this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use await on your browser actions otherwise it performs the actions synchronously.

e.g 
        await browser.get("https://google.com");

Comment: Hi @Raymond, i added the Report and in report it is showing like "function timedout after 5000 seconds"

Comment: @SatishRongala In your cucumber hooks, you should increase the timeout

Comment: if you don't mine can you please let me know in which block i have to update it and what's the syntax for that..

Comment: Here is some documentation on cucumber hooks https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/master/docs/support_files/hooks.md

You will want to add the following to the BeforeAll

setDefaultTimeout(60000);